# GDPR - do I have to resend my cv?

Tags: job-search, internship, united-kingdom, email, legal

I'm in the UK and have been receiving a lot of emails these past few days about the changes brought about by the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR).

I'm currently seeking an internship and have emailed at least 50 CVs in the past 6 months to companies (small sized), the vast - do I have to re-send them to them now?

Here's a link as helpfully suggested by @DarkCygnus:

https://www.corehr.com/blog/gdpr-general-data-protection-regulation-everything-every-hr-leaders-needs-know/

Comment: Why do you think you would need to resend them?

Comment: @DavidK. I read that HR need express written consent that they can keep your cv on file

Comment: @Sally101 would you mind including a reference to the source that says you have to do that? It may help in answering this with a better context

Answer (score 9):

No. GDPR provides for legitimate use for their business purpose. You have sent them your CV specifically for them to use to provide their service to you. They do not need you to opt in to remain a client.

You can opt out if you want.